# Stop scrolling with current offset in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Am having a problem in scrollviewer.
Scenario:

am having a stack panel inside which having a content, from mouse move of that content am showing a popup to rearrange those content.

issue: when am trying to handle mouse move of that content popup shows and also scrolling happening.

expected behavior: scrolling should not happen while handling mouse move.

i have tried `"HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled`" it works fine but it sets the scrollviewer to its initial position, means horizontal offset sets to Zero("0")

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand... You want the functionality of the scrollviewer so you can scroll, but you want it to be locked so you can handle the mouse move from within the objects in the scrollviewer? That's a contradiction. Can you give a real usage scenario so we can understand exactly how this should work in your mind?

Comment: I have described my use case as 

"stack panel inside which having a content, from mouse move of that content am showing a popup to rearrange those content."

let me explain clearly, a stack panel having 10 buttons. this stack panel will be child for scroll viewer. Now i want to reaarrange the buttons position by MouseMove of the buttons. At this time scrollviewer should not scroll and have to retain its current offset until the rearrange completed.

Comment: The problem is, the scrollviewer only functions off those events. How will you know if the user is trying to scroll or to rearrange the buttons?

Comment: The buttons are arranged in a manner having some gap(empty space) between those buttons. so that while manipulating in that space means scrolling should done, else manipulating by buttons means rearranging will done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion, I think the best route would be to store a class level boolean which will determine whether or not to enable scrolling. You'd have to set this according to your needs (Probably the same place you were modifying the visibility before).

The next step would be to set up some events and properties on your scrollviewer so that you can control whether it scrolls or not. You really only need to modify the constructor of the page holding the scrollviewer, and create a handler for the `ManipulationStarted` event. The following assumes your control is named Scroll, and that the variable locked is set to true when the control should not scroll:

```
public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         Scroller.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(scroller_ManipulationStarted);
         Scroller.ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.Control; // Required
      }

      void scroller_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (locked)
         {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Complete();
         }
      }
```